# What is the quickest way to perform a function equivalent to _mm_loaddup_pd in avx?

Tags: c, avx

I want to be able to do the following, if I have the following doubles in memory (in sequential order):

A-> a1| b1| a2| b2

```
__m256d r1,im1;
/*Perform operation here*/
r1-> |a2|a2|a1|a1| 

im1-> |b2|b2|b1|b1|
```

One method I can think of is:

```
t1 = _mm256_load_pd(&A);t1->|b2|a2|b1|a1|
r1 = _mm256_movedup_pd(t1);
t1 = _mm256_permute_pd(&A,0x0101);
im1 = _mm256_movedup_pd(t1);
```

AVX doesn't have a _mm_loaddup_pd() or _mm_load1_pd(). So what is the quickest way(in terms of latency, not necessarily number of instructions) that I could perform this?

Comment: What you have there is pretty good already. I'm not sure if it's possible to do better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is not broadcast/duplication, but shuffle/unpack:

```
/* tmp = |b2|a2|b1|a1| */
tmp = _mm256_load_pd(&A);
/* r1 = |a2|a2|a1|a1| */
r1 = _mm256_unpacklo_pd(tmp, tmp);
/* im1 = |b2|b2|b1|b1| */
im1 = _mm256_unpackhi_pd(tmp, tmp);
```

Comment: I was about to update the answer with this and saw yours.. Yeah, this works